# LDAP Login failing if £ symbol present in password

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP from my Java Application. It is working fine until now. But the customer has reported an issue saying he gets an error while logging into the application if "£" Symbol is present in the password.

I am able to replicate the issue locally. When the password field has the "£" Symbol then the LDAPException is thrown and the log file shows the below error:

```
"LDAP error 49 - AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e -
```

I am using the ldapjdk.jar file in my application.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 49 is `invalid credentials`. I was not able to reproduce your test case using the UnboundID Directory Server: that server handles it just fine. Is there a configuration setting for AD that controls which characters can be used in passwords, or more generally, as an attribute value?

Comment: No, there is no configuration setting for AD that controls the characters to be used in password. Yes, when I debug my java code the LDAPException is caught and it shows LDAP Result code as 49, which is for Invalid Credentials. Interestingly, when I try to bind to the LDAP Server with the same password(having £ symbol) using ldp.exe, I am able to bind to it without any errors.

Comment: So it's not the server. I wonder if your API is doing something weird. If you are in a position to try the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/files/unboundid-ldapsdk-2.3.5-se.zip), do so, and see if you get the same results.

Comment: I tried to connect to LDAP Server from a Stand alone Java class. Using the java class also I face the problem if £ is present in the password. It gives the LDAP error 49. I wonder if the password String which is passed to the LDAP server is in not the required format (UTF-8 and ASCII). How to ascertain it and debug?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the "ldapjdk.jar" library; I'd suggest you to look for a better library as advised by Terry Gardner in above comment!